# HTML Linebreak between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, line-breaks

I am using a simple  line break in a html page to space certain items on a page.

I Google Chrome this seems to work fine but when I load the page in Firefox the line break seems to have no effect at all.

What other way is there of doing this that would work on all web browsers?

The code is posted below. None of the line breaks seem to do anything.

```
echo "</br><b style='font-size:40px;color:white;'>".date('D d F Y   -   h:i A')."</b></br></br>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no closing tag `</br>` since this is an empty tag and either not get closed or get closed by **appending the slash** in the start tag (XML notation): `<br />`.